# Wiremock server serving a pdf as text file (corrupted PDF)

Tags: http, pdf, embedded-jetty, wiremock

I have a standalone wiremock server which is running an embedded jetty behind.I am trying to service a PDF, and I am getting a text document event if the content type is specified as :

```
content-type →application/pdf;charset=UTF-8
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong ?

KR

Comment: *"Any idea on what I am doing wrong ?"* - Your content type contains a char set. Only for text files it is meaningful to have a char set. Thus, you shouldn't be surprised if your file is treated as a text file.

Comment: even removing the charset, I have the same problem...